# Deleting specific lines in a delimited txt file - TextWrangler

Tags: textwrangler

I've got a txt file containing delimited columns:

```
chrI    31  31  0
chrI    32  32  0
chrI    33  33  0
chrI    34  34  0
chrI    35  35  0
chrI    36  36  0
chrI    37  37  0.000967201
chrI    38  38  0.003865064
chrI    39  39  0.008682376
chrI    40  40  0.0154005
chrI    41  41  0.023993446
chrI    42  42  0.034427969
```

I would like to delete all lines ending in '0' but for that not to include any numbers that are 0.01... etc. I've tried replacing ^.*0.*$ with nothing with grep enabled however this deletes the 0.01... values and any thing containing a 0 in the final column. How can I otherwise do this within text wrangler?

Thanks for any help!

- K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^.*0$
```

the dot between 0 and $ has tricked you